# How to crack SHA512 hexdigest passwords with John the Ripper?

Tags: passwords, audit, password-cracking

I've been playing with John The Ripper (JtR) to try to crack/audit a salted password that was hashed with SHA-512, with 20 interactions [according to the source](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/crypto_providers/sha512.rb) (for the curious, this is a Rails app, with the authlogic gem).

If I understood things correctly, JtR expects its hashes in a file, where each hash follows certain format. For SHA512, this format appears to be:

```
username:$6$SALT$HASH
```

which seems to be a format that is compatible with the passwd/shadow files.

My problem is that the hash I have in my DB is a hexdigest while it seems that the hash that JtR expects its in Base64.

Am I right in this ascertion? Is there a way to tell JtR to recognize a hexdigest hash (composed of password + salt) that was 'stretched' 20 times?

Thank you.

Comment: This might help you adding your own dynamic function for this "format": http://blog.thireus.com/john-the-ripped-steak-and-french-fries-with-salt-and-pepper-sauce-for-hungry-password-crackers

Comment: That looks like a custom algorithm. So I'd guess that you'd need to modify JtR to add support for this kind of hash.

Answer (score 2):

From your description it is not clear how the salt and the hash are encoded into the hexdigest in your DB. First, you have to extract the salt and the hash from the digest. Than, you can create the sha512-crypt which is described at http://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=33.